# Anaconda | OpenCV | VS Code - Module cv2 not found

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I know that I am not the only one who got this problem, and also tried to look at different solutions, but they did'nt solved it.

The problem is, simply, that I have installed opencv in an anaconda environment via the following command:

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Checked if it was installed, via:

`python`
 `import cv2`
 `cv2.__version__`

Like explained by the OpenCV website.

Problem is that, coding with VSCode, for which I will have to use it for creating app with PyQt, it tell me that it doesn't find the module. (I have selected the correct environment and checked in the command line inside VSCode, and it is isntalled the library)

Stragenly, yesterday it was working, and then not anymore.
I have tried to uninstall it, install it, update the anaconda navigator, but nothing, no solutions.

Does anyone know how to solve this big issue?

Comment: perhaps check `sys.executable`. likely you have multiple pythons, or you work in a virtual environment, or you installed opencv into a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking `conda run` to execute the command, isn't it?

It's an update of Python Extension:

> Use conda run for conda environments for running python files and
> installing modules. ([#18479](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18479))

[changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog)(28 February 2022).

But it has some problems, it will not take advantage of the sub environments under Anaconda3, although you have selected it in the VSCode. It will be taking the base environment instead.

If you execute `sys.executable`, you can find it out. And if you execute it directly like `python pythonFileName.py` in the terminal, you will find it works.

I had submitted [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18665) on GitHub.

**Update:**

Workaround:

1. [Set "python.terminal.activateEnvironment" to false in the settings.json.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18634#issuecomment-1060686997)
2. [Downgrade to the previous version of the extension which works fine(avoid `conda run`).](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18634#issuecomment-1061699266)
3. Try out the following VSIX which has the potential fix: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/suites/5578467772/artifacts/180581906, Use Extension: Install from VSIX command to install the VSIX.

Reason:

Conda has some problems:

[conda run -n MY-ENV python FILE.py uses the base interpreter instead of environment interpreter.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9587)

[Running using conda run inside already activated environment should be the same as running it outside](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11305)

[conda run does not remove base environment components from $PATH](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11174)

Comment: @MOB Could you have a look at the update?